# Can you improve recommendations on YouTube's main page compared to the ones from sidebar?

Tags: youtube

I usually get lots of random suggestions on the main page, with only a few from the channels I'm watching. Then I go to some video and in sidebar video listing the suggestions are usually much more accurate, both when it comes to my channel subscriptions and also new channels that I might want to watch.

Is there a way to get the sidebar's algorithm working on YT's main page for recommendations?